# Background color and styles does not appear correctly

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at my site http://kaniamea.com/2/ I am trying to get the contentarea appear correctly behind the three Attractions boxes. My css is:

```
#attractions {
    width: 290px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

and this is the code of my main container:

```
#main {
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    width: 950px;
    max-width:100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FBFBFB;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

When I remove     float: left; from  #attractions and replace it it with display: inline-block; it works but I need to figure out another solution with float: left; so this will float correctly on mobile. Is there another way to make the contentarea styles appear behind the boxes?

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to #main selector to clear floats. For more detailed explanation why is this happening look here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: This solution works great but unfortunately not in my case. It hides a few elements that are outside of #main. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I figured it! Thanks!